# NodeRed blocked by trigger execution

Tags: sql-server, triggers, node-red

I installed a trigger to log the logins, because I plan to restrict logins to a range of IP addresses.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [LogonAuditTrigger] /* Creates trigger for logons */
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS '....'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @LogonTriggerData xml,
@EventTime datetime,
@LoginName varchar(50),
@ClientHost varchar(50),
@LoginType varchar(50),
@HostName varchar(50),
@AppName varchar(500)
SET @LogonTriggerData = eventdata()
SET @EventTime = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
SET @LoginName = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @ClientHost = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @LoginType = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginType)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @HostName = HOST_NAME()
SET @AppName = APP_NAME()
INSERT INTO [LogonAudit].[dbo].[LogonAuditing]
(
SessionId,
LogonTime,
HostName,
ProgramName,
LoginName,
LoginType,
ClientHost
)
SELECT
@@spid,
@EventTime,
@HostName,
@AppName,
@LoginName,
@LoginType,
@ClientHost
END
GO
```

So far so good. I tried several tools and everything worked. Logins were logged to the table and I got an overview which user comes from which IP. That was what I expected.

But a few hours later, I got the information, that NodeRed can't login and write to the db anymore. Well, error log tells me no problems from NodeRed.

I dropped the trigger and NodeRed worked again.

After looking again to the login audit table, I mentioned that no login from NodeRed was logged.

FYI, none of the successfully connected users has access to the audit table and I created the trigger with "execute as .." instead of the last question I asked about triggers. With the "execute as .." the other trigger worked and this was a lessons learned.

From this point, it looks like NodeRed has a problem with the trigger. Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Didnt you already ask this? i'm guessing the problem is that your username for nodered (whatever it is) doesn't have access to put data into the audit-table

Comment: Well, this was the problem with the other question. I created the trigger with "execute as .." and none of the other users has write access to the audit table.

Comment: Ok, wrap your code into a try catch and then log the error into some other table. i'm guessing the issue is your table fields are too thin to fully accept one of the varchars. but who knows

Comment: I recommend extended events for this sort of thing.